# why I only can see one spark streaming kafkaReceiver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm confused why I only can see one KafkaReceiver in spark web UI page(8080),
But I do have 10 partitions in Kafka, and I used 10 cores in spark cluster, also my code as follows in python: 
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer",{topic: 10})
I suppose the KafkaReceivers number should be 10 rather than 1.
I’m so confused.
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer",{topic: 10})
```

That code creates 1 receiver with 10 thread. Each thread will attach to one partition and all data will be pulled by 1 consumer using 1 core. All other cores will (potentially) process the data received.

If you want to have 10 receivers, each one attached to 1 partition, using 1 core you should do this: (in Scala, my Python is weak, but you get the idea):

```
val recvs = (1 to 10).map(i => KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer",{topic: 1}) 
val kafkaData = ssc.union(recvs)
```

Take into account that you will need additional cores for Spark to process the received data.

Comment: Thank you so much Maasg, your answer solved my problem. Could I ask which approach do you prefer in practice, 10 Receivers with 1 thread or 1 Receiver with 10 threads please? I'm wondering if it's just one Receiver working, when the single Receiver blocked or crashed the work flow would be blocked.

Comment: @Jack we balance that out depending on load. You could try 5 rec x 2 threads (`{topic: 2}`) or 2rec by 5 threads (`{topic: 5}`). 10 is a bad number of partitions b/c doesn't leave many options. We use magic number 12, so we could do  2 x 6, 3 x 4, ..., 12 x 1