# pyspark parallel processing with multiple receivers

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to implement parallel processing with Spark.  I want to create multiple receivers (not just threads) in spark to receive streaming data from kafka.  I found a link indicating how to do that with scala (see link below).  But I can't find similar codes for pyspark.  Can someone help?

[why I only can see one spark streaming kafkaReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079655/why-i-only-can-see-one-spark-streaming-kafkareceiver/32461021#32461021)

Answer (score -1):

```
numStreams = 5
kafkaStreams = [KafkaUtils.createStream(...) for _ in range (numStreams)]
unifiedStream = streamingContext.union(*kafkaStreams)
unifiedStream.pprint()
```

All additional information you can get from [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) tutorial. Section - Level of Parallelism in Data Receiving.

Comment: Add more detail, please.